# How to sum certain floats in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, floating-point, sum

I wonder how to sum up only the floats in this list,

`list = ['abc', 3.0, 2.0, 2.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]`

I can't find out how to exclude the first string. I would like to do something with

`range(1, len(list))`

as it will need to work on lists with longer lengths, maybe something similar to it with the same effect? For python 3

Comment: If you know you always need to exclude the first element, `sum(lst[1:])`. Don't use `list` as a variable name.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a generator in [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) and [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) to check if something is a float.

```
>>> lst = ['abc', 3.0, 2.0, 2.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
>>> sum(x for x in lst if isinstance(x, float))
8.0
```

Note you should not use `list` as a variable name as it will overwrite the built in `list` class.

Answer (score 1):

```
my_list = ['abc', 3.0, 2.0, 2.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
sum = 0
for i in my_list:
    if type(i) is float:
        sum += i
print(sum)
```

This will result the sum to 8.0